# Unable to extract data from JSON

Tags: json, r

I am very new to R tool and I have received a JSON file where in I have to upload it R as a Table. Please advice me.

I have installed all the packages required for JSON and also have used fromJSON function to derive the data into a variable. However from the variable which is of list type, I am unable to extract the data properly.I have the file for the reference but unable to attach to this tag.

Please let me know your advice on this.

Note: I am unable to attach the JSON file to this ticket. Please let me know how can I attach the sample files.

Comment: Just copy and paste a small sample of the data and code, and show what you want as the result

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am unable to paste the data also please give me any refernce id so that I can send a sample file.

Comment: @Santhosh You can upload the file in `dropbox` and share the link.

Comment: Hey akrun thanks for the idea. I have shared the sample file at the following link.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/o05m50fgof1tmjd/20_30_1201404230721.json?dl=0

Comment: Column Names : Id,Time,Text,likes.....ParentID                        Example Row : 1015236330496..83,timevalue,Hi Thr.If buy...,0,....0

Comment: @Santhosh I updated the solution.  Please check if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(rjson)
lines <- readLines('20_30_1201404230721.json')
json_dat1 <- lapply(lines, fromJSON)
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(json_dat1),
        function(i) do.call(rbind,lapply(json_dat1[[i]][[1]], 
                            as.data.frame.list))))

dim(res)
#[1] 210   7
```

Comment: Hey Akrun ,, thanks a lot for the help however the issues was the data that was converted to table I could see only for first set but there are three different sets of data. For example serach with data word in the file u ll see there are three sets. I could get only for the first set.

Comment: Thank you very much Akrun, the solution works fine. Thanks a lot for your kind help.